# Ultrafilters/prime ideals in a Boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra, filters, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $U$ be an ultrafilter in a Boolean algebra $A$. Does $U$ **necessarily** contains an atom of $A$?

Let $I$ be a prime ideal of the same Boolean algebra $A$. Does $I$ **necessarily** contains the complement of an atom of $A$?

Edit: Sorry, I meant in a **finite** Boolean algebra

Comment: Well, $A$ might be atomless.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is an infinite set, and $I$ is the ideal or $\wp(X)$ consisting of the finite subsets of $X$, then the Boolean algebra $\wp(X)/I$ is atomless. Other atomless Boolean algebras include the Boolean algebra of regular open subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ and the [interval algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)#Examples) of the real numbers.